# How to call web service and stop VPN server in applicationWillTerminate Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, vpn

I have implemented VPN Server logic (NETunnelProviderManager) and start tunnel on NETunnelProviderSession using startTunnel(options: ["ipv4": dnsIpv4]) method. VPN Working fine and started properly. I want to stop VPN tunnel in applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) method when application terminating. I have also put code logic for that but it will not stop VPN And I also want to call API (Web-service) when application going to terminate.

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

//Stop VPN
   self.vpnService.disable { (error) in
   }

//Perform API Calling
   self.myAPI()

}

Comment: Don't execute functions that require a relatively long time to run in `applicationWillTerminate`, since there is simply not enough time to execute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your implementation of this method has **approximately five seconds** to
>   perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before
>   time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate